# add-apt-repository gives no result, cursor keeps on blinking for long time

Tags: apt, add-apt-repository

```
root@Gagan-PC:~# add-apt-repository ppa:slimbook/slimbook
```

and I get no result after this, it just keeps on blinking

Comment: You haven't told us your release of Ubuntu, but is your release supported by that PPA?

Comment: 18.04 , yes it is supported

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the repository manually.

Open a terminal, do *not* login as root, and type the following:

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/slimbook/slimbook/ubuntu `lsb_release -sc` main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slimbook-ubuntu-slimbook-`lsb_release -sc`.list
```

Verify that you've added the repository:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slimbook*
```

Add the GPG key (per N0rbert's comment):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys BE80F1EEB3838E61E42091B378A22399981017FC
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt update
```

NOTE: You probably already know this, but you should not be logging into a terminal as a root user; use `sudo` instead.

Comment: All is great, but you forgot to add GPG key. Seems that OP has networking issue.

Comment: I agree with N0rbert's statement, you probably have a network issue. Nevertheless, I did add the GPG key, just to have a complete answer.

Comment: thankyou soo much sir